# Get request data (GET) in a Symfony (5) formType without using data_class

Tags: symfony

I'm building a formType to filter products on a collection page. You can set multiple select boxes which makes other auto filled or unnecessary. I want to be able to manipulate the formType based on the data like when using a data_class object. I'm not using data_class because the search isn't a persisted object which is saved to the database. I'm using a GET form.

For example 2 select boxes:

- category
- productType

When setting a category makes some of the productTypes unnecessary. So i want to not show it.
To do so in the formType I need the data of the request (GET) but I can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from the form, you can use `$form->getData()`.
As you're in a `GET` context, I suspect you can take advantage from [FormEvents](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) (take a closer look to [POST_SET_DATA](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#pre-populating-the-form-formevents-pre-set-data-and-formevents-post-set-data) event) and get rid of values you don't need.

One other thing I would like to point out, is that you still can use some kind of object that's not persisted to DB, like DTO or whatever.

Forms and entities are not related anyhow, neither in the usage nor in the intentions.

Comment: I was not able to get the data via `$form->getData()`. Probably because there is no `data_class` connected tot the formType. I've made use of `createFormBuilder` inside to the controller instead of `createForm` with the formType. In my controller I used the request object to modify the form.